# Flutter: PageView seems to ignore PageController's page property after setState

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I'm having the following problem: My library `easy_image_viewer` has a request to add swipe-to-dismiss. I implemented it using the `Dismissible` widget. However, when the user zooms in on an image, I noticed I had to find a way to "deactivate" the Dismissible widget because otherwise the user can't pan around on the zoomed-in image. I solved that by using `setState` and a `dismissDirection` variable on the state that can be either `none` or `down`.
Now for the weird part: Whenever I call `setState` and the `dismissDirection` changes, the PageView jumps back to the first item. I've tried using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, but to no avail.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/thesmythgroup/easy_image_viewer/tree/pagecontroller_problem_demo

Simply run the app (`example/lib/main.dart`), tap on `Show Multiple Images (Simple)`, swipe to the second image and use pinch & zoom to zoom in. You'll notice it jumps back to the first image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fork -> clone -> git checkout pagecontroller_problem_demo and then try the last paragraph!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the dismiss direction you can use `confirmDismiss` i opened a PR for you to check [here](https://github.com/thesmythgroup/easy_image_viewer/pull/17/files)